# Swift Firebase loads images too many times

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to load users "posts"(images and their descriptions) from Firebase. Everything seems to be working fine at first and I see 3 posts in my viewController but when I upload a new image to the Firebase the amount of all the posts by the user multiplies and then the app loads not 4 but 8 posts. Why is this happening?

here's my snapshot

```
Snap (qUJAq6aeNGYUeSsl9RmzldNpTME3) {
"508D22DE-E865-460E-A011-A9170E0AB6A8" =     {
    description = n;
    downloadURL = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/findit-2f6eb.appspot.com/o/images%2F1A18AFAD-815C-417C-8C7A-226343FD0256.jpg?alt=media&token=46a6c929-a5ec-49e4-b6ca-aca896618fe0";
};
"D8434D58-1193-421D-8DFE-982983CB20D4" =     {
    description = Maaa;
    downloadURL = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/findit-2f6eb.appspot.com/o/images%2F059C91E8-95A8-44C6-9779-F678E2B9E033.jpg?alt=media&token=46ff5654-abec-49dc-bbb8-afae0eb6f1bd";
};
"F0E47F44-AE22-4D80-B173-E2168CB20B94" =     {
    description = 7;
    downloadURL = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/findit-2f6eb.appspot.com/o/images%2F1EA82DCA-FFE2-4B79-931C-28B66C7729AB.jpg?alt=media&token=8eaa2e02-5af8-4b43-adf2-2ac9214f902e";
};
}
```

MyPostsTableViewController

```
import UIKit

 import Firebase



  class MyPostsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
let user = Userr()
var downloadURL = ""



var desCription = ""
var allPosts = [String]()
let currUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    let ref =  Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(currUser!)
    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        print(snapshot)

        let dictionary = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
        var keys = Array(dictionary.keys)
        self.allPosts = keys

        for index in 0...(keys.count - 1) {
            self.allPosts.removeAll()
            self.user.descriptions.removeAll()
            self.user.downloadUrls.removeAll()
        ref.child(keys[index]).child("description").observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            ref.child(keys[index]).child("downloadURL").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot2) in
                self.user.descriptions.append(snapshot.value as! String)
                self.user.downloadUrls.append(snapshot2.value as! String)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            })
        })


        }

    })


}




override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows



        return user.descriptions.count

}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as!MyPostsTableViewCell



  //  print("downloadUrls Count \(user.downloadUrls.count)")


    cell.descriptionLabel.text = user.descriptions[indexPath.row]

   let profileImageURL = user.downloadUrls[indexPath.row]

    cell.imageVieeew.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    cell.imageVieeew.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(profileImageURL)



    return cell

}



}
```

PostViewController

```
  import UIKit
  import Firebase


class PostViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

let user = Userr()

@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!
@IBAction func postToServer(_ sender: Any) {

       self.user.allow = false
    // successfully authenticated user
    if imageViw.image != nil && textField.text != ""{

        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let postName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let imagesFolder = Storage.storage().reference().child("images")

        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageViw.image!, 0.2){
            imagesFolder.child("\(imageName).jpg").putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion:{
                (metadata, error) in

                if let error = error{
                    self.presentAlert(alert: error.localizedDescription)
                } else{
                    if let downloadURL =  metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {

                        let currUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                         let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(currUser!).child(postName)
                        ref.child("downloadURL").setValue(downloadURL)
                        ref.child("description").setValue(self.textField.text!)

                    }
                }

            })


            }

    }
    else {
        // we're missing something
        presentAlert(alert: "You mus provide an image and a message for your post.")
    }


}
```

Comment: Add `Child added observer` , by which firebase only gives you a new child. If you add `Type value observer`, It will return all its children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time a new post is added, the code attaches another listener that executes, so you'll append descriptions and downloadUrls once for each listener you've attached. There's no need to listen separately to each child because any changes to them will be triggered by the original `.observe` listener since the `.value` of the path has changed. Instead, iterate through the childSnapshots and append the data as needed. It would look something like this, although I haven't tested it with your data and code so you may have to tweak it.

```
   let ref =  Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(currUser!)
   ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        print(snapshot)
        self.allPosts.removeAll()
        self.user.descriptions.removeAll()
        self.user.downloadUrls.removeAll()

        guard let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }
        for snap in snapshots {
            self.user.descriptions.append(snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "description").value as! String)
            self.user.downloadUrls.append(snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "downloadURL").value as! String)
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
```

Comment: @JenPerson is this design sustainable? If there were 1,000 posts the client side device would have to redownload all 1,000 posts. This seems like it would work fine for smaller apps but certainly not a good idea for apps with a lot of data.

Comment: If the concern is sustainability, then a data model with paging or infinite scrolling could be created, which would query a few entries at a time. Using a data model that has `childAdded`, `childRemoved`, and `childChanged` is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here `ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in`

`.value` causes all of the data to be returned. Thus you get duplicated data. Change that to `.childAdded` and only the new post information will be returned to your app.

Also at some point you're probably going to want to remove that observer. Since I don't know how your app works I'm not sure when that will be, but it's something to keep in mind.

Use `ref.removeAllObservers()` to do that.

Take a look at other ways to get data [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data)